# Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

I am using xcode 6.4 with OS version 10.10.1. When am installing Podfile to my project it's getting below mentioned error. Please advice.

Error : [!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`. You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

Comment: What's your podfile?

Comment: Welcome to SO, sathya. You mentionned suggestions you had (in the last sentence) without telling us if you *did* try and what the results were.

Comment: Podfile is 'pod 'Firebase/Core'

Comment: I tried to install 'pod 'Firebase/Core' in the project by terminal. While installing pod i got above mentioned error.